# How do I switch from my integrated AMD GPU and set my Nvidia GPU as my main GPU?

Tags: nvidia

I'm new to Linux and in need of help.
I have an ASUS TUF FX505DT with a Ryzen 5 CPU and a GTX1650 GPU.
I need to switch my GPU from the integrated AMD GPU and set my dedicated Nvidia GPU as my main GPU.
Can anyone tell me how I can do that?

I have tried a few distros and the only one that seems to detect and set my Nvidia GPU as the main by default was POP_OS. However, I really want to get this to work on my Xubuntu.

I read somewhere that I should just install the driver and it would set my Nvidia as the main after that but it didn't work for me (I checked and it was still running software on the integrated AMD GPU. I really need to get it to detect and set my Nvidia GPU as I do a lot of work with 3D Blender.

I also read somewhere that you can set it from the bios menu but that also didn't work(or rather my bios menu didn't have the option).

I don't want to have to go back to Windows because I found that I like Linux way more because it's very customizable and snappy!

Any assistance/insight/advice would be greatly appreciated!

Please help! Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

First, check if you have the GPU.

```
lspci -k | grep -A 2 -i "VGA"
```

Then if you have Nvidia's Card, install drivers. Currently, I would recommend 440, but 450 is the latest.

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:graphics-drivers
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install nvidia-driver-440
```

reboot, then run nvidia-settings.
And to chose different profiles:

```
prime-select query
sudo prime-select nvidia
```

Comment: Hi! Thanks for replying! Like I said in my original post, I have already installed the driver. I first tried the 440 but whenever I go to Nvidia settings, it would come out as blank. The same thing happened when I installed the 450 driver. It just shows me a blank.When I do 'neofetch', I can see that it's there. But I noticed that it's below the AMD integrated GPU unlike when I use 'neofetch' on Pop_OS. I read somewhere that Prime only works with Intel CPUs? But there must be a way because it works when I use Pop_OS.

Comment: So when you open nvidia-settings it doesn't load right.
If it is so, try starting it from the terminal. 
If it shows an error, it's probably because of two reasons, one your driver has issues because you tried multiple nvidia dirver. Try removing it fully, then install ubuntu-drivers. Then restart.
Another reason is when your system is not plugged in or is battery saver mode. Apparently nvidia cards have some issues with this. Try connecting with power supply then a reboot.